# PHP script that enables client communication with custom hardware

Tags: php, client-server

We have a wireless device (WIFI enabled) that calls a PHP script to enter data into MySQL db. Am trying to find a way to see if the server (through PHP script) can "connect" to the client device (has a microcontroller but doesn't have an OS or display) and pass some data.

The client is a electronic board connected to a gate and the server needs to tell the device to open the gate. Seems to be pretty straight forward but am new to this.

Comment: If the client calls the PHP script, why not send the data in the response?

Comment: You can't control hardware is in the traditional sense with PHP. You can however write the code you wish to use in a seperate file (with the language your hardware can interpret, be it STAMPII, Arduino or something else) and then have PHP fetch the appropriate code and send it as a response. This might be of help: http://www.arduinoprojects.com/node/10 (PHP via USB Arduino example).

Comment: One crude format is to make the client devices ping the server continuously for any actions or data that needs to be sent/received. Without an OS (to listen on a port) on the client device the server cannot possibly connect. Golden rule of communication :)

Comment: @Truth: Yes that is what we are doing.. Just wanted to make the server initiate the communication.

Answer (score 0):

If the client is **configured to listen on a specific port**, you can open a socket connection to it from the server (using `fsockopen()`).

You'll need to configure the client though, which I have no idea how to do because your client is nothing standard.